# How do I run Java applets from Command Prompt?

Tags: java

So a little background that may answer some questions on why I'm asking this. I took a java programming class my freshman year in high school, then I stopped. I'm trying to pick it up again, but I forgot almost everything. I still have some of the old programs I saved and I'm trying to get some of them working, but I can't get this one working (I'm pretty sure it was working on the school computers, but I can't remember).

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;
//import java.applet.applet;

public class PP2_14 extends JApplet
{
    public void paint (Graphics page)
    {
        final int MID = 150;
        final int TOP = 50;

        setBackground (Color.cyan);

        page.setColor (Color.blue);
        page.fillRect (0, 175, 300, 50); //ground

        page.setColor (Color.yellow);
        page.fillOval (-40, -40, 80, 80); //sun

        page.setColor (Color.white);
        page.fillOval (MID-20, TOP, 40, 40); //head
        page.fillOval (MID-35, TOP+35, 70, 50); //upper torso
        page.fillOval (MID-50, TOP+80, 100, 60); //lower torso

        page.setColor (Color.black);
        page.fillOval (MID-10, TOP+10, 5, 5); //left eye
        page.fillOval (MID+5, TOP+10, 5, 5); //right eye

        page.drawArc (MID-10, TOP+20, 20, 10, 190, 160); // smile, change to frown and make this not a frown

        page.drawLine (MID-25, TOP+60, MID-50, TOP+40); //left arm
        page.drawLine (MID+25, TOP+60, MID+55, TOP+60); //right arm

        page.drawLine (MID-20, TOP+5, MID+20, TOP+5); //brim of hat
        page.fillRect (MID-15, TOP-20, 30, 25); //top of hat
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, but it won't run. I figured that i need to insert "public static void main(String[] args)" somewhere, and that's what command prompt tells me, but I don't know where.
I have tried putting it after

```
public class PP2_14 extends JApplet {
```

and after

```
public void paint (Graphics page) {
```

but neither works. Where should I put the main method? Is there something else I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Be  respectful to others. @Hamuel If you think question is not good comment to improve it. Don't insult anyone here.

Comment: sorry if it sound like an insult but that is actually my answer to his problem he can put the main method in any class and compile them or create a new class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` in them and write his code

Comment: From the code posted here, I think the OP is biting off a bit more than he's ready for in re-learning Java.  Rather than start with a fairly complex graphical example, you'll need to look at a really basic Swing application example.

Comment: The main method is the initial invocation of your program.  It is a method and has to have the { .. code here .. } brackets.  Inside those brackets, you'll need to instantiate an instance of your class and set it to a reference of the type of your class so that you can call your paint method using the reference.

Comment: Maybe start with working code, and work backwards? The Java website has tutorials on this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've compiled the code successfully. Try using the generated class inside a `.html` file as:

```
<html>  
    <body>  
        <applet code="PP2_14.class" width="300" height="300">  
        </applet>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Calling it via a `main()` might need to initialize/override `Graphics` which I believe you don't intend to do for now.

Comment: Oh yeah i think i remember that bit now. I have html files for other similar programs, but not this one though. How do i get the html file?

Comment: @VolTorian you can create a new html file and add the content in the answer above and then open that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there a specific reason why the background stays white instead of cyan? I'm able to change the colors of the other components but not the background.

Comment: @VolTorian That can be another question though. I would suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651915/setbackground-doesnt-work-on-applet-background?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

When you compile and run code the function "public static void main(String [] args)" is where information from the command line for when the program is run goes. args is an array of strings that holds such values. When writing a program in java, there must be one main function (that is: public static void(String [] args)) for the program to be compiled and run. This is an overly simplistic answer for a topic that can definitely be more fleshed out.

Also, it is general practice to have the main function after all the other functions have been written, as when the compiler goes through the code it is important that functions have been defined before they are called.

Ps. This would have been left as a comment, however, I do not have the required 50 reputation.